# MSVC and FreeGlut Compiler Error

Tags: c++, static, visual-c++, freeglut

Receiving alot of these messages when compiling which is making compiling a simple program very time consuming.

```
freeglut_static.lib(freeglut_callbacks.obj) : warning LNK4204: 'z:\CST328\Lab1\block\Release\vc90.pdb' is missing debugging information for referencing module; linking object as if no debug info
1>freeglut_static.lib(freeglut_cursor.obj) : warning LNK4204: 'z:\CST328\Lab1\block\Release\vc90.pdb' is missing debugging information for referencing module; linking object as if no debug info
1>freeglut_static.lib(freeglut_display.obj) : warning LNK4204: 'z:\CST328\Lab1\block\Release\vc90.pdb' is missing debugging information for referencing module; linking object as if no debug info
```

Is there anyway to prevent this? Would making working on my assignments much more pleasant. :)

EDIT:
I Am using Microsoft Visual C++ Express 2008.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your pdb file is out of sync with the library binary

in Windows, the [pdb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd4f8bd1(VS.71).aspx) holds the debug information for a module.  it is linked to a particular build.  if your rebuild your library you have to produce a new pdb file.  the pdb file your have is out of sync so you either have to delete (or rename) it (find a file freeglut_static.pdb) or recompile the library and produce an up to date pdb file.

Comment: I cannot find the freeglut.callbacks.pdb file.

Any other suggetions? I have rebuilt the Visual Studio 2008 Static project. Should putting the new lib files in their correct place fix the error?

Comment: the file should be freeglut_static.pdb